# Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to run my Service Fabric App locally but I'm receiving the follow error:

> Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: source

What is `source` in this context?  And why is it `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ApplicationManifest.xml` I defined `<EnvironmentOverrides>` w/ one `<EnvironmentVariable>` entry but I didn't define that `<EnvironmentVariable>` in `ServiceManifest.xml`.

[Sample project to illustrate](https://github.com/spottedmahn/Experiments/tree/master/ServiceFabricEnvTest)

---

**ApplicationManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="Application1Type" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Web1_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
    <Parameter Name="OverrideTest" DefaultValue="Do I Get a Useless Error Message?" />
  </Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Web1Pkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="Code">
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="OverrideTest" Value="[OverrideTest]" />
    </EnvironmentOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  ....
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

**ServiceManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="Web1Pkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="Web1Type" />
  </ServiceTypes>

  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>Web1.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
    <!--Uncomment the EnvironmentVariables to get rid of Value cannot be null. >Parameter name: source-->
    <!--<EnvironmentVariables>
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="OverrideTest" Value="Uncomment-me to get rid of the error" />
    </EnvironmentVariables>-->
  </CodePackage>
  ...
</ServiceManifest>
```